# How do I do an E2E test for a web application that uses OWIN, SignalR and Selenium/Protractor - I can only get the first test to pass

Tags: c#, selenium, signalr, owin, xunit.net

I am trying to perform E2E tests where in each test I create a new website and roll back a database.  I am using SignalR to push data to the client.  My issue is only my first test is passing when I run them all at once, even though each passes individually. **How can I run a bunch of tests serially, cleaning up SignalR/Owin in between each run?**  I couldn't find any examples of SignalR + E2E testing, though the official documentation did show unit testing.

Though some deduction and logging I think it was SignalR not disposing and/or initializing correctly.  Here's what I did to confirm this is the issue:

1. Opened Visual Studio 2013.
2. Created a Web Application that uses Wewb API called "SignalRSandbox".
3. Managed NuGet packages -> Installed `Microsoft.AspNet.Signalr`
4. Managed NuGet packages -> Installed `angularjs` (My website uses angular; to keep things as close as possible to my real environment I'm using Protractor instead of Selenium)
5. Added a class called `StartUp`:
6. Added a class called `ChatHub`:
7. Added an html file called `index`:
8. Created a new Class Library project called "SignalRSandbox.Tests"
9. Added a reference to the web site project
10. Managed NuGet packages -> Installed `xunit`
11. Managed NuGet packages -> Installed `Protractor`
12. Managed NuGet packages -> Installed `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver`
13. Managed NuGet packages -> Installed `Microsoft.Owin.Hosting`
14. Managed NuGet packages -> Installed `Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener`
15. Managed NuGet packages -> Installed `Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles`
16. Added a class called `MyTest`:

Sure enough only the first test passes:

**StartUp.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

namespace SignalRSandbox
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

**ChatHub.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace SignalRSandbox
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.html** (some of the code may seem a little funky - I was just trying to get Protractor/Selenium to wait properly).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="ng">
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="message" />
        <button type="button" id="send" onclick="send()">Send</button>
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <ul id="discussion"></ul>
    </div>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var send;
        $(function () {
            var q = [];
            var loadMessages = send = function () {
                q.push({ 
                    name: $('#displayname').val(), 
                    message: $('#message').val()
                });
                $('#message').val('').focus();
            };

            var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
            chat.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
                var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
                var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
                $('#discussion').append('<li id="discussion' + $('#discussion').children().length + '"><strong>' + encodedName
                    + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
            };
            $('#displayname').val(prompt('Enter your name:', ''));
            $('#message').focus();
            var sendMessages = function () {
                q.forEach(function (i) {
                    chat.server.send(i.name, i.message);
                });
                q.length = 0;
            };
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                sendMessages();
                send = function () {
                    loadMessages();
                    sendMessages();
                };
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**MyTest.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using Protractor;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xunit;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles;
using Microsoft.Owin.FileSystems;
using OpenQA.Selenium;

namespace SignalRSandbox.Tests
{
    public class MyTest : IDisposable
    {
        private NgWebDriver _driver;
        private IDisposable _site;
        private string _url;

        public MyTest()
        {
            this._url = "http://localhost:8765/index.html";
            this._site = WebApp.Start(this._url, appBuilder =>
            {
                // SignalR
                new Startup().Configuration(appBuilder);

                // Allow static content through
                var options = new FileServerOptions();
                options.FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem("../../../SignalRSandbox");
                appBuilder.UseFileServer(options);
            });

            this._driver = new NgWebDriver(new ChromeDriver());

            this._driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
            this._driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
            this._driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            // We have to use the WrappedDriver otherwise the alert will cause an error.
            this._driver.WrappedDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(this._url);

            // Enter the name
            var alert = this._driver.WrappedDriver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            alert.SendKeys("j");
            alert.Accept();

            // Enter a message
            this._driver.WrappedDriver.FindElement(By.Id("message")).SendKeys("test");
            this._driver.WrappedDriver.FindElement(By.Id("send")).Click();
            // Enter another message
            this._driver.WrappedDriver.FindElement(By.Id("message")).SendKeys("test1");
            this._driver.WrappedDriver.FindElement(By.Id("send")).Click();

            Assert.Equal("j:  test", this._driver.WrappedDriver.FindElement(By.Id("discussion0")).Text);
            Assert.Equal("j:  test1", this._driver.WrappedDriver.FindElement(By.Id("discussion1")).Text);
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test()
        {
        }

        // All subsequent tests fail
        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test2()
        {
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test3()
        {
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (this._driver != null)
            {
                this._driver.Dispose();
            }
            if (this._site != null)
            {
                this._site.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tests are run using the test explorer (I think I installed an XUnit.NET Visual Studio plugin, as well).

---

**Update**: By switching to NUnit instead of xUnit and by using the [ApplicationDomain](https://bitbucket.org/zastrowm/nunit.applicationdomain/wiki/Home) extension I was able to do the following, but in doing so I end up calling Initialize and dispose in my test method, which I don't like having to repeat myself, but it does get the job done.

If someone can get this working without using separate app domains I'll accept.

Here's the updated **MyTest.cs VER 2**:

```
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using Protractor;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles;
using Microsoft.Owin.FileSystems;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace SignalRSandbox.Tests
{
    public class MyTest
    {
        private NgWebDriver _driver;
        private IDisposable _site;
        private string _url;

        public void Intialize()
        {
            this._url = "http://localhost:8765";
            this._site = WebApp.Start(this._url, appBuilder =>
            {
                // SignalR
                new Startup().Configuration(appBuilder);

                // Allow static content through
                var options = new FileServerOptions();
                options.FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem("../../../SignalRSandbox");
                appBuilder.UseFileServer(options);
            });

            this._driver = new NgWebDriver(new ChromeDriver());

            this._driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
            this._driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetScriptTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
            this._driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));

            // We have to use the WrappedDriver otherwise the alert will cause an error.
            this._driver.WrappedDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(this._url);

            // Enter the name
            var alert = this._driver.WrappedDriver.SwitchTo().Alert();
            alert.SendKeys("j");
            alert.Accept();

            // Enter a message
            this._driver.WrappedDriver.FindElement(By.Id("message")).SendKeys("test");
            this._driver.WrappedDriver.FindElement(By.Id("send")).Click();
            // Enter another message
            this._driver.WrappedDriver.FindElement(By.Id("message")).SendKeys("test1");
            this._driver.WrappedDriver.FindElement(By.Id("send")).Click();

            Assert.AreEqual("j:  test", this._driver.WrappedDriver.FindElement(By.Id("discussion0")).Text);
            Assert.AreEqual("j:  test1", this._driver.WrappedDriver.FindElement(By.Id("discussion1")).Text);
        }

        [Test, RunInApplicationDomain]
        public void Test()
        {
            this.Intialize();
            this.Dispose();
        }

        // All subsequent tests fail
        [Test, RunInApplicationDomain]
        public void Test1()
        {
            this.Intialize();
            this.Dispose();
        }

        [Test, RunInApplicationDomain]
        public void Test2()
        {
            this.Intialize();
            this.Dispose();
        }

        [Test, RunInApplicationDomain]
        public void Test3()
        {
            this.Intialize();
            this.Dispose();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (this._driver != null)
            {
                this._driver.Dispose();
            }
            if (this._site != null)
            {
                this._site.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call `MapSignalR` multiple times in the same AppDomain you should pass in a new  `DefaultDependencyResolver` each time. If you don't pass in your own `IDependencyResolver` to `MapSignalR`, it will use the one referenced by `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver`.

The test failures you are seeing are likely caused by SignalR dependencies getting disposed when you are disposing `MyTest._site`.

You can specify your own `IDependencyResolver` for each call to `Configure` like so:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

namespace SignalRSandbox
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
            {
                Resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver()
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** The above solution will make `GlobalHost` unusable, because each `GlobalHost` property references `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver` which is no longer being used by SignalR.

You can work around this by resolving the appropriate type from the `IDependencyResolver` SignalR is actually using. For example, instead of using `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager`, you could do the following:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver();
    var connectionManager = resolver.Resolve<IConnectionManager>();
    var myHubContext = connectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();

    app.MapSignalR(new HubConfiguration
    {
        Resolver = resolver
    });
}
```

Alternatively, since you're *not* running multiple SignalR endpoints simultaneously, you can just reset `GlobalHost.DependencyResolver` before your call to `MapSignalR`. Then you can continue to use `Globalhost`:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver();

    // GlobalHost.ConnectionManager now references the IConnectionManager
    // provided by the DefaultDependencyResolver instantiated in the line above.
    var myHubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();

    // SignalR will use GlobalHost.DependencyResolver by default
    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! Adding: `config.Resolver = new DefaultDependencyResolver()` causes SignalR to seem to appear to cause one of my two hubs to start working.  If I set the dependency resolver like that am I allowed to do: 'GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>().Clients.All.myMethod()' ?  That's the only weird thing about it.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain why GlobalHost stops working if you provide a custom `IDependencyResolver`.

Comment: Thanks!  "Alternatively, since you're not running multiple SignalR endpoints simultaneously..." does that imply this only works with a single hub/single endpoint on that hub (I have a client method and a server method - each on a different hub in actuality)?

Comment: All hubs share a single SignalR endpoint (the path is "/signalr" by default). PersistentConnections always get their own endpoint, but it seems that you aren't using those. The main thing I was getting at is that if you were calling `MapSignalR` multiple times in your Configuration method (which you can do if you use the overload to `MapSignalR` that takes a path) and you don't want the two endpoints to interfere with each other, you shouldn't use `GlobalHost` since it would cause the endpoints to share state.

Comment: Got it!  So I was doing my SignalR configuration in `WebApi.Start` AFTER Web API.  As it turns out the Web API configuration instantiated something the depended on a SignalR `IHubContext`.  Point being IT WORKED after I reversed the two so SignalR is configured first. I've been trying to get E2E tests on my site for a 2 - 3 days now (different issues).  All three just ran sequentially for the first time a minute ago.  THANK YOU SO MUCH :)